# Simulate a click in c++

Tags: c++, click, simulate

I am making a game in c++, and, for a button in the menu, I want it to go back and then simulate a click. My menu consists of a Main Menu with Play, How to play, Credits and Quit. Inside the How to play, there is a back button. After I press it, I want it to go back and then simulate a click because the Main Menu does an animation after a click. I think that I can do it using SendInput() but I do not know how to use it. Any help on how to simulate that click, please?

I have this code for the back button:

```
void UIButtonBack::Update()
{
   if (AEStaticPointToStaticRect(&(inv_camera * gAEMousePosition), &mPosition, mScale.x, mScale.y))
   {
       mColor = AEGfxColor(255, 105, 180, 225);
       if (AEInputMouseTriggered(0) || AEInputKeyTriggered(VK_SPACE) || AEInputKeyTriggered(VK_RETURN) || AEInputKeyTriggered('X'))
       {
              gAEGameStateNext = gAEGameStatePrev;
              //SendInput(WM_LBUTTONDOWN, ,);           
        }
    }
    else
    {
         mColor = AEGfxColor(255, 20, 147, 225);
    }
 }
```

Comment: do i understand correctly, that you actually just want to play the animation and the simulated button click is just to trigger that? What exactly happens when the button is clicked? just do the same when `back` is chosen on the menu...

Comment: So I'm guessing `Windows`? It might be a relevant tag to add.

Comment: Probably don't even need to simulate a click, just call the same function that is normally triggered by a click?

Comment: I wanted to simulate a click because of 2 things: There is a screen with the name of the game and a "click to continue" that appears before the main menu. The second reason is because it is a class project and if I copy paste code I loose points

Comment: Ok, I have already solved it doing a bool and setting it to true when the back button is clicked. Thank you for your time!